# AWS CI CD with codepipline error - attached log

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a Django project with code pipleine

what I've done :

1. Created Elastic beanstalk env py version 3.6

eb-activity.log returns this error

I tried running pip upgrade on the env pushing to git but that didn't fix it.
Any suggestions ? :)

```
[2020-09-21T08:53:56.134Z] INFO  [19227] - [Application update code-pipeline-1600678386608-0fd34dae5393dbc6a31d126a16f4daabf6dc966d@6/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03deploy.py] : Activity execution failed, because: Collecting appdirs==1.4.4 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3b/00/2344469e2084fb287c2e0b57b72910309874c3245463acd6cf5e3db69324/appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting apturl==0.5.2 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apturl==0.5.2 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for apturl==0.5.2 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
  You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 20.2.3 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  2020-09-21 08:53:56,127 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: Collecting appdirs==1.4.4 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3b/00/2344469e2084fb287c2e0b57b72910309874c3245463acd6cf5e3db69324/appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting apturl==0.5.2 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apturl==0.5.2 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for apturl==0.5.2 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
  You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 20.2.3 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  2020-09-21 08:53:56,127 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

Comment: Can you ssh into your EB instance and manually install your `requirements.txt`. This way you can get more info on what's happening.

Comment: Yep, I'll try to do that

Comment: @Marcin 
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Collecting appdirs==1.4.4
..
Do I need to upgrade the python version ?

Comment: Your EB env uses python 3.6. Maybe you executed by mistake python 2.7?

Comment: Hey yeah I installed 3.6 . my requirements.txt waas generated from pip freeze which makes it super long. could that cause the problem ? 

I'm deleting each package that causes an error and will give another update in 10 minutes thanks man :) @Marcin

Comment: How did it go? Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: @Marcin Hey thanks for the follow up question. 

I managed to install the packages on the SSH instance, I'm trying to push it with codepiple but I'm getting WSGI path error. 

What should my WSGI path point to if this is the project structure 

-pythoninvoice
 -django-project
  requirements.txt
 -virtualenv

django-project folder contains the manage.py file